# How can I make an image bar to stay on top with the menu on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have downloaded the HTML5 template from http://html5up.net/prologue. The template is responsive, and the navigation menu stays on top in mobile to be clicked to show the menu items. What I am trying to achieve is to include the image at top that would stay fixed like the menu in the mobile view. I have tried adding a div as below:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:99;">
<img src="nameofimagefile"/>
</div>
```

But I am not able to achieve what I need. The image stays on top but blocks or hides the menu items. Could you help me in achieving this?

The following images may make it clear on what I am trying to achieve:

**Present Website:**
[image: Present Website]

**What I Would Like:**
[image: What I Would Like]

Comment: try use `display: inline` in a div

Comment: display: inline doesn't make any difference.

Comment: like this? http://cssdeck.com/labs/vkfbmkgf

Comment: Yes! But the image should fill the width till the menu and should be included in a div as I am planning to add more button images also that will be staying at top. The code should fit in the prologue template.

Comment: like this? http://cssdeck.com/labs/vkfbmkgf The example works here but I don't know how it works with your template. I need full code.

Comment: Yes! But where should i include the code in prologue template. I tried adding it inside the main div but doesn't stays on top. You can download the full code in http://html5up.net/prologue.

Comment: The template seems to be little complicated. It seems that menu button adds through the javascript only if screen is narrow. So if screen wide enough menu button just will disappear.

Comment: You are right. What can I do then for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it works only on a narrow screen do this:

In **/js/init.js** file find *sidePanelToggle* object and add to its *html* property your div with buttons

```
// ...
sidePanelToggle: {
                    breakpoints: 'narrower',
                    position: 'top-left',
                    side: 'top',
                    height: '4em',
                    width: '5em',
                    html: '<div data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="sidePanel" class="toggle"></div>' + '<div style="position: fixed; display: inline; top: 0; right: 5px; color: white">Your buttons here</div>'
// ...
```

Comment: I don't know how to make it works in both modes. That suggestion only for narrow mode

Comment: That's sufficient for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
#main section.cover {
    padding: 0;   /*for all the @media css*/
}
```

and then add image tag before the h2 tag within header tag

It will work !

Comment: Your code is just displaying the image at the top. It is not staying at top when we scroll in mobile browser.

Comment: there are so many "#main section.cover paddings" including for mobile..  i think you may miss to comment that...